# Set fill color of center column in amCharts Step Count

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to use amCharts and have an interface that looks alot like the step count chart here:

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/step-count-chart/

I want to be able to set the fill color of the column in the middle of the chart. Also when the chart is dragged the color of the columns should change so that it is always the column in the center that has the special color.

Is this possible?

Comment: is it a fixed number of columns?

Comment: No, there could be any number of columns.